# keeping error logs in SPSS using syntax

Tags: spss

I am running SPSS from python, which means that I cannot see the errors that arise while my SPSS is running. In SPSS, is there syntax to save errors in a separate log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after following up on JKP's suggestion of using OMS to capture warning and log blocks, I looked through the SPSS help section. The following code saves a full log to a separate PDF file:

OMS
  /SELECT WARNINGS LOGS
  /DESTINATION FORMAT=PDF IMAGES=NO
   OUTFILE='C:\Directory\filename.pdf'.

At the end of the file, I have:

Omsend.

In order to close OMS.

I hope this helps somebody in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running with SetOutput("OFF"), so you don't see the errors.  However, you can capture all the warning and log blocks with OMS and write them to a text file.  They will still appear in the regular Viewer output unless you specify VIEWER=NO with OMS.

There is also an api, spss.GetLastErrorMessage, and another, spss.GetLastErrorLevel that you can use in a try-except block, however in many cases the message api isn't able to give you the actual error text.

Comment: Hi JKP, thanks for your response. Do you happen to know the syntax to capture all warnings with OMS and write them to a text file? That is exactly what I am looking for.